# Making Banner Auto-resizing (CSS)

Tags: css

I am attempting to make the banner resize automatically depending on the size of your monitor.

This is the current code:

```
body {
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    background: #0b0b0b url({resource="settings/header_bg.png" app="core" location="global"}) no-repeat scroll center top;
    margin: 0;
```

I have tried some different things, but none have worked so far.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Is the banner the body background?

Comment: You probably looking for `background-size: cover;`.

Comment: Can you please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This will help us troubleshoot much faster. :)

Comment: What do you mean when you say banner? What do you mean when you say "resize automatically"? What are those "different things" you tried? How did they not work? (Please note that "doesn't work" is not a proper problem description. Instead tell us what you expected, why you expected it, what you got instead, and why you didn't expect what you got.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use background size at 100% width. Depending on the height of your page, cover might be too tall

```
body {
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    background: #0b0b0b url(http://www.placekitten.com/1900/500) no-repeat scroll center top;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    margin: 0;}
```

Edit: 100% will make the image the full width of your screen so it "resizes automatically" depending on the device/screen. The auto for the height value makes it so that your image aspect ratio is preserved because you probably wouldn't want it all stretched out right? But that does mean that your image is going to grow taller when you widen the window.

It should also be noted that putting a heading banner as a background image on the body tag is a bit unusual. Most of the time, people put a header image in a div tag. This would allow you to set a fixed pixel height on the div that's not the whole page if you like and then you could crop part of the image if that's what you're going for.

Like others have noted, it's really not that clear what you're trying to do and more explanation would help.

Comment: It kinda answers it but the problem is that the picture is now getting bigger both width and lengthwise. So it looks like this now: https://gyazo.com/052f83c01156c667d47531fc25e87c41
But it should look like this: https://gyazo.com/9329f91ee7366449568bb78de91562dd

Comment: But those are two different size windows. I don't understand

Comment: The picture itself seems to be coming to large in height.
Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: You can set a height as well instead of auto. Or just set the height and make the width auto

Comment: Edited my answer with more explanation

Comment: I am very sorry for explaining everything so bad and probably wasting your time.
I will keep trying myself as it seems like a lot of people get bothered.

Answer (score 0):

background-size: cover
resizes the background image to cover the entire body, but the image may be stretched or cut.

background-size: contain
resizes the background image to make sure the image is fully visible.

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.3846;  /*18px*/
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #0b0b0b;
    background-image: url({resource="settings/header_bg.png" app="core" location="global"});
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Note that the first child container in the body gets a min-height:100% to enable vertical scrolling.

```
<body>
  <div style="min-height:100%;">
    YOUR PAGE
  </div>
</body>
```